# MicroSD card MP3s are deleted/unplayable on Note 4

Tags: internal-sd, compatibility, mp3, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a brand new Samsung 128GB EVO Micro SDXC for use with my Note 4. I did get it from eBay, but it came in actual Samsung packaging and looks legit. If it's a fake, they did a hell of a job.  I formatted it on my Mac in good ol' FAT 32 and copied about 70 gig of music over with a USB adapter, then reinstalled in my phone. Using DoubleTwist, suddenly I only had folders in the 0 - C title range, all else has been deleted.  Also, certain mp3 tracks within those retained music folders wouldn't show as playable, the "unknown file format error" yet all of these files are good ol' mp3 files..When viewing the files in Android File Transer, they look just fine. Coping them BACK from the card to my Mac, they're unplayable, and VLC says they're "undf", so perhaps corrupt.

So I get frustrated and reload the missing D - Z files (several hour copy processe), reload my phone and use the generic "music" player by Samsung.  Now I've got 0 - D folders, nothing else! I've also tried VLC (won't load!) and PowerAmp, these 'unknown' mp3 are still unplayable. I don't see how the card is bad, as it was brand new in the OEM packaging.  Should I just reformat again and try again?  Just so strange how it retains some folders in alphabetical order then gives up on down the list...?
Thank you,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

What about you try and format it on the tablet itself instead of formatting it elsewhere.

sdxc's I believe are catchy and not compatible with every hardware. While you did format it your Mac I have no idea what was the default allocation size of the cluster and the tablet might not like that.

Also check that the card is firmly inserted in its place.

But before anything else... Check that your Samsung Tab 4 actually supports 128Gb card since my guess is that it doesn't but only 64 - check their specs.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks gitr.  It's the Samsung Note 4, not the tablet.  Yes, it supports up to 128 gb. I did originally format it on the phone, but it put it in a format that OS X couldn't recognize, some sort of windows based, perhaps exFat, I don't recall.  Granted, this is an old MBP running OS X 10.6.8

Comment: well, I suggest an approach that helps: e.g. either format (externally) the card in a format that the os (operating system) of the Samsung Note 4 recognizes (I guess they will be a lot, could be ext3, ext4?) or install a patch to the OS X version you use that recognizes the SN4 format... Remember: FAT32 supports 32Gb max partitions, that is why micro$oft invented "exFAT" which is prone to corruption if you do not unmount / eject it properly.